# Stack view distribution acting unexpectedly

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

How do I prevent my stack view from spreading the items within it like this?  I want the height of the stack view to dynamically increase according to the content inside.
[image]

I currently have the distribution set at `Equal Spacing`.  If I change the distribution to `fill` or `fill proportionally`, it either stretches one of them drastically or puts a huge space in between some items.

[image]

My constraints are as follows:

[image]

If I get rid of `height = 896`, I get an error saying that it needs constraints for Y position or height.

For each item, I'm just setting the height anchor:

```swift
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

Comment: A stack view with NO arranged subviews has no intrinsic height. If you're laying out your scroll view and stack view in Storyboard / Interface Builder, give your stack view a Placeholder Intrinsic height to avoid the *needs constraints for Y position or height* warning. At run-time, the arranged subviews (labels, buttons, etc) will determine the stack view's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the stack view to adjust its size dynamically based on the content inside, then you should explicitly specify the size of all the items contained inside the stack view (unless the internal view can resize itself based on the content like `UILabel`) and don't set any height constraints for the stack view itself.

So in your case, you would want to set height constraints for `UITextField`, `UIButton` & `UITextView`. Once the constraints are set, just set the distribution to `fill` or `fillProportionally` (based on your use case)

As for the `needs constraints for Y position or height` error, give it a `Y position` not a height constraint.